# Merging commits together in a branch

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I am new to Git.

I have created a new branch `new_branch`. I have done all changes and commits in a different branch `old_branch`. Now I want to pick some commits from the branch `old_branch` to `new_branch` by `git cherry-pick`. For that I first need to know which commits are in that branch and then pick them and merge with `new_branch`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to pick ALL the commits from old_branch into new_branch? If so, just do "git checkout new_branch; git merge old_branch"

Comment: No I don't want to pick all commits but some of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout new_branch
git log old_branch
```

The log will show  each commit in old_branch, with a long string like "cf5e845a13866239eb87f2593d6edc6e273decc5", just above the commit message. This is the commit hash. You can then do

```
git cherry-pick <commit hash>
```

for each commit you want. I would recommend doing them in chronological order (working up the log from the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to accomplish this, here are a couple for the commit listing:

```
git log --cherry new_branch..old_branch --oneline
```

will show you all the commits in `old_branch` that can't be reached from `old_branch`.

Or another way:

```
git checkout old_branch
git cherry new_branch --abbrev=6 -v
```

which will show you commits within the `old_branch` (without commits that introduce the same change), and will mark commits to indicate if they have `-`, or have not '+' yet been cherry-picked into the `new_branch` E.g:

```
+2bdcd1 1st commit     (Has not been cherry picked)
-8de6cc 2nd Commit     (Has been cherry picked)
+8ac1ee 3nd Commit     (Has not been cherry picked)
```

In either case, you can then use

```
git cherry-pick <commit>
```

Although you'd want to checkout the 'new_branch' in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

The method given by @naomi will work fine, but there's a much easier way.  You have your `old_branch` branch starting from some commit on some other branch, like this:

```
A --- B --- C --- D      <-- devel (let's say it's branch devel, anyway)
        \
          E - F - G - H  <-- old_branch
```

You've made a branch `new_branch` coming off some commit (B or C or D, perhaps) and you want to pick out some of the commits E, F, G, and/or H (maybe a much longer string of commits, but this should illustrate things).

Normally, if you wanted to take an unpublished sequence of work (perhaps `old_branch` is just such a sequence) and "move it" on top of the latest (commit D), you'd just do:

```
$ git checkout old_branch   # get onto old_branch
$ git rebase devel          # and rebase it onto commit D in "devel"
```

What that does is make "copies" of commits E through H, adding each one after "D".  Then it peels off the label `old_branch` (which used to name commit H) and pastes it onto the copy-of-H, giving this:

```
A --- B --- C --- D                    <-- devel
       \           \
        \           E' - F' - G' - H'  <-- old_branch
         \
          E - F - G - H                    [abandoned, see footnote]
```

What you want is to pick some commit, let's say C (wherever you created your `new_branch` above) and do the same thing, but *not* "peel off the label" `old_branch`.  Furthermore, you want to pick and choose which of E, F, G, and H go there.  When it's all done you want the label `new_branch` added.  That's actually really easy.  Instead of creating branch `new_branch` at commit C, create it at commit H, the head of `old_branch`:

```
$ git checkout old_branch; git checkout -b new_branch
```

Now `new_branch` and `old_branch` are identical content-wise, but have different names.

Now you can simply `rebase -i` (interactive, lets you pick and choose) `new_branch` onto the point you want it to go.  I've been assuming commit `C` here, which I have been assuming is one step back from the branch-tip named `devel`, so I will run with that:

```
$ git rebase -i --onto devel~1 devel new_branch
```

After you pick and choose the way `rebase -i` allows (and resolve any conflicts from deleting some commits and `git rebase --continue` to continue after resolving), you'll end up with something like this, depending on which commits you take and which you delete.  I'll assume you delete F but keep the rest:

```
A --- B --- C --- D                    <-- devel
       \      \
        \       E' - G' - H'           <-- new_branch
         \
          E - F - G - H                <-- old_branch
```

You can actually do this all with just two commands (vs 3 above), as `git branch` can create `new_branch` at the same point as `old_branch`.  Also, it's likely you want to `rebase -i` onto the *tip* of whatever branch, i.e., rather than rebasing `--onto devel~1` you just want to rebase onto (the tip of) `devel`.  In this case you don't need the `--onto` part after all:

```
$ git branch new_branch old_branch
$ git rebase -i devel new_branch
```

The result here is almost the same as before except now commit E' comes off D instead of C:

```
A --- B --- C --- D                    <-- devel
       \           \
        \            E' - G' - H'      <-- new_branch
         \
          E - F - G - H                <-- old_branch
```

This is basically what I do when I am reworking unpublished changes.  If I'm on (say) branch `revise` I rename it to `revise-0`, create a new `revise` at the same place, then `rebase -i` and clean it up a bit.  After one pass of that I may decide to revise it again, so I rename `revise` to `revise-1` and create a new `revise` at the same place as `revise-1`, then `rebase -i` again, etc.  All my old stabs at whatever-it-is are still there if I want them, until I decide I don't want them; then I delete all the -0 -1 -2 ... names.

---

Footnote: The commits marked "abandoned" above are still there—they're held against garbage collection via the reflog—but eventually the reflog entry expires and they go away in a `git gc`.  Until then they're mostly invisible: `git log --all` and `gitk --all` won't show them, for instance.  You can run these commands with `--reflog`, but even then, with no branch labels, they're still a little tricky to find.  I like hanging on to them for a while, hence the multiple branch name workflow above.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's easier, but more satisfactory for git-savvy people like us. For a git beginner it's one to several hours of reading and understanding the concepts it involves, so naomi's one is actually easier